# How to break a string in C with /

Tags: c, string, tokenize

I have a string with the following pattern :

```
char *str = "ai/aj/module_mat.mod";
```

and I want to select module_mat as my final string for the further logic. I have tried to used rindex() so that I can get the final part of the string. But I am not able to do this in C. What am I doing wrong?

The code I am trying is -

```
char *first = rindex(str, "/");
char *first = strtok(first, ".");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is right here:

```
char *str = "ai/aj/module_mat.mod";
```

Since `str` points to a constant, this should be:

```
const char *str = "ai/aj/module_mat.mod";
```

Now your compiler should show you the other problems.

Similarly:

```
char *first = rindex(str, "/");
```

Since `rindex` is returning a pointer into the constant you passed it, that pointer should also be `const`.

```
char *first = strtok(first, ".");
```

Hmm, what do the docs for `strtok` say:

> If a delimiter byte is found, it is overwritten with a null byte
>   to terminate the current token, and strtok() saves a pointer to the following byte; ...

So `strtok` modifies the thing the pointer points to, so passing it a pointer to a constant is *bad*! You can't modify a constant.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the string literal is immutable, so it is very dangerous to bind it to a mutable char pointer. First fix your code:

```
const char* str = "ai/aj/module_mat.mod";
```

Next, use `strchr`:

```
#include <string.h>

const char* p = strchr(str, '/');
if (p != NULL) {
  ++p;
  printf("Last part: %s\n", p);
} else {
  printf("No '/' found in string %s.\n", str);
}
```

If a `/` is found in the string, `p` will point to it, and hence `p` can be used as the suffix substring of the original string, and there's no need to modify the original string. We advance `p` by one to skip past the `/` and are left with the final part of the string.

Comment: Okay. This helps. And what If I want to extract only "module_mat" from above specified string using strtok(), rindex() and some other possible function? Because I am getting an error there as well.

Comment: @AniruddhaTekade: Well, you would need a mutable string for `strtok` and the like, so you'd need to make a copy or something like that.